# How to get device width and height?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiscreen, cgsize

In Objective-C we can get device width and height by using following code :

```
CGRect sizeRect = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame
float width = sizeRect.size.width
float height = sizeRect.size.height
```

**How can do this in with Swift ?**

Comment: FYI - `applicationFrame` does not give the screen size. It gives the application size. It's better to use `bounds` instead of `applicationFrame` if you want the screen size.

Comment: Yes, rmaddy you are right. I already made this changes in my app. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

I haven't tried but it should be..

```
var bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
var width = bounds.size.width
var height = bounds.size.height
```

Comment: Its give OutOfScope Value.. When I am using your code Its give me typecasing error.

Comment: Oh, ,, yes its CGFloat not float .. check now

Comment: Why not to use Swift auto type inference ? simply like: var bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

Comment: @Aks It's safer and more readable to explicitly define the type.

Comment: how would you display the CGFloat values as an Int?

Comment: why is the result: (0.0, 0.0, 667.0, 667.0)?

Comment: FYI: `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` with latest sdk.

Comment: If the device is in landscape the width and height will be opposite

Answer (score 25):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
let width = screenBounds.width
let height = screenBounds.height
```

Comment: why am I getting: Use of unresolved identifier 'UIScreen'...?

Comment: Probably need to import UIKit

Answer (score 20):

If you want to use it in your code. Here you go.

```
func iPhoneScreenSizes() {
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let height = bounds.size.height

    switch height {
    case 480.0:
        print("iPhone 3,4")
    case 568.0:
        print("iPhone 5")
    case 667.0:
        print("iPhone 6")
    case 736.0:
        print("iPhone 6+")
    case 812.0:
        print("iPhone X")
        print("iPhone XS")
        break
    case 896.0:
        print("iPhone XR")
        print("iPhone XS Max")
        break
    default:
        print("not an iPhone")

    }
}
```

Comment: @Jeff "not an iPhone"  XD

Answer (score 17):

@Houssni 's answer is correct, but since we're talking Swift and this use case will come up often, one could consider extending `CGRect` similar to this:

```
extension CGRect {
    var wh: (w: CGFloat, h: CGFloat) {
        return (size.width, size.height)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
let (width, height) = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.wh
```

Hooray! :)

Answer (score 13):

(Swift 3) Keep in mind that most width and height values will be based on device's current orientation. If you want a consistent value that is not based on rotation and offers results as if you were in a portrait-up rotation, give *fixedCoordinateSpace* a try:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var sizeRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame
var width    = sizeRect.size.width
var height   = sizeRect.size.height
```

Exactly like this, tested it also.

Comment: Also without `;` LOL XD

Comment: Yeah like me and i'm really scared now! If i begin to write everything in `Swift` without semicolons and then again in `ObjectiveC` i will have probably `Ω(n)` compiling error LOL

Comment: @MatteoGobbi I consider using semicolons good practice... *use them.*

Answer (score 6):

Since you're looking for the device screen size the simplest way is:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
let width = screenSize.width
let height = screenSize.height
```

Answer (score 5):

This works great for **Xcode 12**

```
func iPhoneScreenSizes() {
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        switch height {
        case 480.0:
            print("iPhone 3,4")
        case 568.0:
            print("iPhone 5 | iPod touch(7th gen)")
        case 667.0:
            print("iPhone 6 | iPhone SE(2nd gen) | iPhone 8")
        case 736.0:
            print("iPhone 6+ | iPhone 8+")
        case 812.0:
            print("iPhone X | iPhone XS | iPhone 11 Pro")
        case 896.0:
            print("iPhone XR | iPhone XS Max | iPhone 11 | iPhone 11 Pro Max")
        default:
            print("not an iPhone")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

A UIScreen object defines the properties associated with a hardware-based display. iOS devices have a main screen and zero or more attached screens. Each screen object defines the bounds rectangle for the associated display and other interesting properties

Apple Doc URL :

> https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwindow/1621597-screen

To get Height/width of ur user's device with swift 3.0

```
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an updated list of the sizes within a useable function:

```
func iScreenSizes() {
            let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
            print("Device height: \(height)")
            switch height {
            case 480.0:
                print("iPhone 3 | iPhone 4 | iPhone 4S")
            case 568.0:
                print("iPhone 5 | iPhone 5S | iPhone 5C | iPhone SE")
            case 667.0:
                print("iPhone 6 | iPhone 7 | iPhone 8 | iPhone SE(2nd gen)")
            case 736.0:
                print("iPhone 6+ | iPhone 7+ | iPhone 8+")
            case 780.0:
                print("iPhone 12 Mini")
            case 812.0:
                print("iPhone X | iPhone XS | iPhone 11 Pro")
            case 844.0:
                print("iPhone 12 | iPhone 12 Pro")
            case 896.0:
                print("iPhone XR | iPhone XS Max | iPhone 11 | iPhone 11 Pro Max")
            case 926.0:
                print("iPhone 12 Pro Max")
            case 1024.0:
                print("iPad 1st gen | iPad 2 | iPad 3rd gen | iPad mini | iPad 4th gen | iPad Air | iPad mini 2 | iPad mini 3 | iPad Air 2 | iPad mini 4 | iPad 5th gen | iPad 6th gen | iPad  mini 5")
            case 1112.0:
                print("iPad Pro 2nd gen 10.5'' | iPad Air 3")
            case 1194.0:
                print("iPad Pro 3rd gen 11.0'' | iPad Pro 4th gen 11.0''")
            case 1366.0:
                print("iPad Pro 1st gen 12.9'' | iPad 2nd gen 12.9'' | iPad 3rd gen 12.9'' | iPad Pro 4th gen 12.9''")
            default:
                print("not listed in function")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

While @Adam Smaka's answer was close, in Swift 3 it is the following:

```
let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
let width = screenBounds.width
let height = screenBounds.height
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 static func getDeviceType() -> String
    {
        var strDeviceType = ""
        if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
            case 1136:
                strDeviceType = "iPhone 5 or 5S or 5C"
            case 1334:
                strDeviceType = "iPhone 6/6S/7/8"
            case 1920, 2208:
                strDeviceType = "iPhone 6+/6S+/7+/8+"
            case 2436:
                strDeviceType = "iPhone X"
            case 2688:
                strDeviceType = "iPhone Xs Max"
            case 1792:
                strDeviceType = "iPhone Xr"
            default:
                strDeviceType = "unknown"
            }
        }
        return strDeviceType
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`UIScreen.main.bounds` will be deprecated in future version of iOS. Use
`view.window.windowScene.screen`

```
 let height = view.window?.windowScene?.screen.bounds.height ?? 0
 let width = view.window?.windowScene?.screen.bounds.width ?? 0
```

Answer (score 1):

let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4 I had to use NSScreen.main?.deviceDescription

> ```
> let deviceDescription = NSScreen.main?.deviceDescription          
> let screenSize = deviceDescription![.size]
> let screenHeight = (screenSize as! NSSize).height
> ```